# Calling Script User's Calendar -GAS

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-sites

I am currently building a Google Site for the branch of the company I work for.
As part of this site, we have a page hosting a web app that upon accessing grabs the current user's ID and uses javascript to generate custom page content including things such as the individual's holiday and uniform requests.

As part of this page, we would also like to display the user's own primary calendar in the page. I am aware of how to embed calendars within the web app, however, I am struggling with finding a way to call the user's own calendar.

Is there a way of doing this based on their userID, or would I need to gather all of their calendar Id's and then consult our database for the individual's calendar Id when they load the page in order to embed it?

All thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: Isn't the default calendar ID the same as the users email address?

Comment: @SandyGood I think by calendar id, he means ids for multiple calendars than can be created within a single user's gmail account

Comment: @SandyGood Yes it is! I hadn't even noticed that. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to get the user's calendar, you can do this using:

[getAllOwnedCalendars()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#getallownedcalendars) - Gets all calendars that the user owns.

```
// Determines how many calendars the user owns.
var calendars = CalendarApp.getAllOwnedCalendars();
Logger.log('This user owns %s calendars.', calendars.length);
```

[getCalendarById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#getcalendarbyidid)
Gets the calendar with the given ID.

```
// Gets the public calendar "US Holidays" by ID.
var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(
'en.usa#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com');
Logger.log('The calendar is named "%s".', calendar.getName());
```

[getCalendarsByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#getcalendarsbynamename)
Gets all calendars with a given name that the user owns or is subscribed to. Names are not case-sensitive.

```
// Gets the public calendar named "US Holidays".
var calendars = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName('US Holidays');
Logger.log('Found %s matching calendars.', calendars.length);
```

Comment: Although a simpler solution has been presented in that their primary calendar has the same ID as their email address which is all I need for my usage; I am going to mark this as the answer as the first function will likely be more useful for anyone else wanting this question answered for a less simple usage than my own. Thank you very much.